# Issue with css to make it look like two grid cells (rows) are merged

Tags: css, gwt

I am trying to make two rows, in the first column, in a GWT Grid look like they are merged (you can merge columns; however, not rows). So I have the following:

```
gridOAS.getCellFormatter().setStyleName(1, 0, "gwt-Row-Span-Bottom-Green");
gridOAS.getCellFormatter().setStyleName(2, 0, "gwt-Row-Span-Top-Green");
gridOAS.setWidget(1, 0, lblCamping);
```

And the css:

```
.gwt-Row-Span-Bottom-Green {
    border-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #9AF96B;
}
.gwt-Row-Span-Top-Green {
    border-top: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #9AF96B;
}
```

However, I still get a white line between the two grids.

Comment: How about using [FlexTable](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlexTable.html)? Its cells can be set to span multiple rows or columns.

Comment: Did you inspect the element to know why the border is still showing? As in, is it still showing because some other style is overriding yours? Is it because it just isn't loading even your changes? Those are different problems with different solutions.

Comment: I agree with @Adam, `FlextTable` is the way to go. You can use  [FlexCellFormatter](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlexTable.FlexCellFormatter.html) to set `colspan` and `rowspan`.

Comment: I am shying away from FlexTable as I have read that it is slow. I have used FlexTable extensively and am trying Grid to see if I can get performance improvement. I will try to inspect the element. I am not a programmer and doing this in my spare time so will need to find out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep using the `Grid` you can add `border-collapse: collapse;` style.

Like this:

```
gridOAS.addStyleName("gwt-Table-Collapse");
```

CSS:

```
.gwt-Table-Collapse {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Hi Adam, this did not do the trick for me. I will try to inspect to see what is going wrong.